# LESS/CSS: Is it possible to wrap a class around the outside of another without HTML?

Tags: html, css, less, semantic-markup

If my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="purely-aesthetic-wrapper">
    <section>
        …
    </section>
</div>
```

…is it possible to omit the outside div from the HTML and do something like this (with LESS):

```
section {
           enclose-with(.purely-aesthetic-wrapper);
         }
```

Sorry if it's an obvious question but I'm not having much luck finding the answer.

Comment: LESS ***is*** CSS so if you can't do it with CSS, you can't do it with LESS. If you have some CSS in mind, please include a sample of the desired output.

Comment: What is your use case for wrapping section with .purely-aesthetic-wrapper - is it purely for style?

Comment: @zzzzBov what about `margin: @a + 10px;`? I can do that with LESS but not with CSS? :-)

Comment: @tborychowski, you're misunderstanding the statement. That code you've written compiles into CSS, which is what the browser then uses on the page. So while you're defining a "variable" in less, it's truly more of a constant because it doesn't change at runtime. In the end, the statement is still `margin: <value>`. LESS doesn't magically add features to CSS, it makes writing CSS easier.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand your point now. This "LESS is CSS" was a bit confusing (as it's not exactly what it says).

Comment: less isn't css. its javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no, it's not possible.

LESS is css pre-processor and it has nothing to do with HTML/DOM-tree